# Convert String delimeter

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array of dates

```
    foreach ($result as $value) {
           $specialclose[]=str_replace("-", ", ", $value);
    }
   return json_encode($result);
```

This is the result `["25-12-2014","26-12-2014"]`

I need this output `[[25-12-2014],[26-12-2014]]`

Comment: So you try to use a string as array, forget `var`, and return `false` inside an array? Seems like a few things went wrong...

Comment: Sorry ClosedDates is a php $closedDates ="[[25, 12, 2014], [26, 12, 2014]]";

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `closedDates` as a string, not an array, change your variable definition to this:

```
var closedDates = [[25, 12, 2014], [26, 12, 2014]];
```

Note the lack of double quotes around the value.

Comment: Or use `JSON.parse` to convert JSON string to array, if the former becomes from external JS code